# How to do pre and post method call of loadComplete and onSelectRow of jqGrid genecally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, extend

I have special implementation for my grid.
For this I wrote some code in `onSelectRow` and `loadComplete` methods of **jqGrid**.

In `onSelectRow` I need to update a global array and in `loadComplete` method I have to access the global array and need to some manupulation in jqGrid.

Till then I am okay. I've already done this. 
Now I want to extend these two method in such a way that is implementation will be generic (other grid can use this without writing any code).

For that I thought of below steps.

1. I want to add a new js (e.g: jquery.jqGrid.additional.js) in my html with jqGrid.js
2. I want to assign my global variable by the data array of jqGrid
3. In this js I want to check the value of multiselect of the grid
4. If the value is true, then I want to extend onSelectRow, loadComplete methods in such way that jqGrid execute both my methods and the code written in onSelectRow, loadComplete methods also.

For example I have `preLoadComplete` and `postLoadComplete` which need to be executed just before and after `loadComplete`  method execution. Similarly this hold true for onSelectRow method also.

I wrote below code in jquery.jqGrid.additional.js and then didn't get the alert (1), alert (2) after jqGrid load.

It only execute the code written in loadComplete method of jqGrid.

```
var oldLoadComplete = $.fn.jqGrid.loadComplete;

$.jqGrid.extend({
   loadComplete: function (){
      var ret;
      // do someting before
      alert(1);

      ret = oldLoadComplete.call (this);

      // do something after
      alert(3);

      return ret; // return original or modified results
   }
});
```

I tried a lot with this and spent many hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extend `$.jqGrid`, not `$.fn.jqGrid`. In the first line that would mean that `$.jqGrid` doesn't even exist and that all elements would not have access to your modified `.jqGrid` plugin but still to the default.

Though I tried to extend `$.fn` with a "new" append method did not work. You might have to overwrite those methods explicitly. I could imagine that jQuery has some safety routines for itself and plugins built in in the `$.extend` method.

```
var oldLoadComplete = $.fn.jqGrid.loadComplete;

$.fn.jqGrid.loadComplete = function( ) {
    alert('pre');
    var ret = oldLoadComplete.apply(this, arguments); // In case any arguments will be provided in future.
    alert('post');
    return ret;
};
```

Edit:

Forget about all that. It is irrelevant. After looking into jqGrid's source code on GitHub a little, it is obvious that jqGrid does not even use something like `$.fn.jqGrid.loadComplete`. That is something you made up yourself. Instead, it creates another object which provides a list of possible properties and defaults which then is overwritten by custom defaults and finally by the function parameter you pass in with your call to jqGrid.

I found out that jqGrid triggers two events `jqGridLoadComplete` and `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` on your set of matched elements (i.e. `this`) before and after the call to the loadComplete callback respectively.

So basically, you cannot use your attempt. Instead, the only solution that comes to my mind is to overwrite the jqGrid "constructor" (i.e. `$.fn.jqGrid`) using the same method and apply listeners to `this` like so:

```
var oldJqGrid = $.fn.jqGrid;

$.fn.jqGrid = function( ) {
    this.on('jqGridLoadComplete', function( jqEvt ) {
            alert('Pre');
        })
        .on('jqGridAfterLoadComplete', function( jqEvt ) {
            alert('Post');
        });
    return oldJqGrid.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

About your multiselect... I don't know what you're talking about. I have only very limited time myself and have to deny further assist for now.

Sincerely.

Comment: Hi Derija, Thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion I added the above code in jquery.jqGrid.additional.js. My jqGrid looks like as below, $("#appAndContextTable").jqGrid({
 datastr: jsonString,
 ........,
 loadComplete: function () {
   alert('Need to implement');
 }
});                                                               When I load the grid, i am getting the alert written in loadComplete  method. I am not getting pre and post alerts. Please help me how do I get pre, post alerts also.Also how can I get the value of the property multiselect in my own defined loadComplete method?

Comment: @user1591670 Just a notification about an update of my post. You might want to read it. Plus I suggest before posting another question to browse a little the source code of the project you are trying to expand. Helps a lot. ;) Figuring this stuff out about jqGrid took me about 10 Minutes.

Comment: Thank you Derija for your help. My problem is solved. You really helped me a lot. Also I found the way to get the value different attributes of jqGrid. Thanks Again.

Comment: Hi Derija, one thing i just noticed that I wrote my jqGrid code like $("#appAndContextTable").jqGrid({ datastr: jsonString, ........, loadComplete: function () { alert('Need to implement'); } }).jqGrid('navGrid','#appAndContextTablePager',{cloneToTop:true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true}); Then I am getting error "jqGrid - No such method: navGrid" if I add the above code as you suggested in another js.Even onSelectRow is also giving same error. Basically all other events bind with the grid are not working once grid load is done if i add the code. Please help me!!!